# How can I repeat a function in python 3?

Tags: python, for-loop

So here is my code:

```
membership_data = open("C:\\Users\\user\Desktop\Pre-release\membership_data.txt", "w")

def ValidateMemberID(MemberID):
    if len(MemberID) !=6:
        return("Wrong Format")
    elif MemberID[:1] == (MemberID[:1]).lower():
        return("Wrong Format")
    elif MemberID[1:3] == (MemberID[1:3]).upper():
        return("Wrong Format")
    elif (MemberID[3:]).isdigit() == False:
        return("Wrong Format")
    else:
        return("Correct Format")

def inputdata():
    Name = input("Please input member name")
    MemberID = input("Please input member ID")
    ValidateMemberID(MemberID)

    if ValidateMemberID(MemberID) == "Correct Format":
           NameID = [Name, MemberID, "\n"]

    else:
        print ("Invalid MemberID")

    membership_data.writelines(NameID)

for _ in range(5):
    do()
    inputdata(_)


membership_data.close
```

The issue I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Pre-release\task_3.1.py", line 31, in <module>
    do()
NameError: name 'do' is not defined
```

What I want to do is to input 5 different records upon the first instance of my program. Essentially I need to run `inputdata()` for 5 times. However, my `for in range do` function keeps giving back this error. I tried different ways of writing it but to no avail.

Comment: What is the do() supposed to do? Why can't you just delete this line?

Comment: function do() is not defined. Please define it.

Comment: (1) remove the call to the non-existent function `do()` (2) remove the `_` argument in the call to `inputdata()`

Comment: The last line should also be `membership_data.close()` (with the brackets) if you want to call the function that will close the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must delete 'do()' from your code

```
for x in range(5):

    inputdata()

membership_data.close()
```